# Open links from array

Tags: python, arrays, list, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have a csv file containing many links. My goal is to scrape through them all. I'm trying to open them using for loop but my array from csv file looks like this [['www.example.com'], '[www.google.com']].

I think this is the problem that causes error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Because when I tried to use this list - data = ["https://www.google.com/", "https://www.bbc.co.uk/"]
it worked.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

with open('neduplikuotas.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

#data = ["https://www.google.com/", "https://www.bbc.co.uk/"]
#print(data)

for element in data:

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(element)
    htmlParse = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for paragraph in htmlParse.find_all("p"):
        print(paragraph.get_text())
```

Comment: Your `csv` looks like `[['www.example.com'], 'www.google.com']]` or the result of reading your `csv` looks like that? If your `csv` is simply one line of comma separated links, then the `csv` module is overkill. You can just use `str.split(',')`.

Comment: yea when i read csv looks like [['www.example.com'], ['www.google.com']], if i try to use data.split(',') ir gets me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' So i need to get rid of these [ ] or there is other solution which i still don't get

Comment: I meant more along the lines of `data = csvfile.read().strip().split(',')`. But this changes depending on how the `csv` file is structured.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that way. And I just found how to make these elements not in bracket so I can do both ways now. Thank you.

```
data = [''.join(ele) for ele in data1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code works with `data = ["https://www.google.com/", "https://www.bbc.co.uk/"]` but you want it to work with `data = [['www.example.com'], '[www.google.com']]`, you can simply select the first element in the list that has added:

```
for element in data:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(element[0])
    htmlParse = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for paragraph in htmlParse.find_all("p"):
        print(paragraph.get_text())
```